# Javascript: update document after infinite scroll

Tags: javascript, dom

On an infinitely-scrollable page, the document element does not reflect the new content that was appended to the bottom of the page.

```
console.log(document.body.innnerHTML); // prints the document on initial page load
var scrollingElement = (document.scrollingElement || document.body);
    scrollingElement.scrollTop = scrollingElement.scrollHeight;
console.log(document.body.innnerHTML); // does not print document with new content
```

PS:

Testable on `https://news.google.com/`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have a few notes here why your investigation might be wrong not the result of it:

1. You have a typo in innerHTML (there is one `n` too much)
2. You might just be *not seeing* that part that has changed in the code, but it's there. If you do this:

   ```
   const x = document.body.innerHTML;
   document.scrollingElement.scrollTop = document.scrollingElement.scrollHeight;
   console.log(x == document.body.innerHTML);
   ```

   You can see that this is `false`
3. https://news.google.com/ does not seem to be infinitely scrollable. At least not how I use it. Anyhow, `2.` shows a difference

Comment: Can you state the page that you have successfully tested this on? It returns true on this page: https://pyk92zvnw0.csb.app/
PS: The code is run with Chrome DevTools

Comment: There might be a problem with synchronicity here: The commands to scroll and the following command to read the `innerHTML` of the `body` might get executed right after one another before anything else runs in your browser, so no other action is taken and the DOM ist still the same. You can try replacing the last line with `setTimeout(() => console.log(x == document.body.innerHTML), 5000);`

Answer (score 1):

There is no `innnerHTML`, but only `innerHTML`.